# Empty cell values in column after publishing report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

I have a report in SSRS (BIDS) that shows seven different columns. First one shows name. The other shows some data in number/currency format. All data comes from same dataset. All data shows when viewing in preview. Then i publish and try so show it, all columns shows data except the first, the one with name... The columns that shows are exactly the same number as names so no problem there, it´s like the names are invisible. Has any one experienced this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the fields from where the dataset get it´s data. I changed my name to only "dimension path" + ".[MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME]. Then i added a new query field with field source ending with ".[MEMBER_CAPTION], see picture. Then i used the "member_caption field to show in column.

Now it works both in BIDS and in external environment.

[image: dataset properties]